# How to reuse a style into same StyleSheet

Tags: react-native, react-native-stylesheet

I am using React Native, and I want to reuse a style within the same StyleSheet. My styles are as follows:

```
buttonContained: {
        borderRadius: 8,
        backgroundColor: Colors.primary,
        padding: 15,
        height: 48,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    buttonOutlined: {
        padding: 15,
        borderRadius: 8,
        height: 48,
        borderColor: Colors.primary,
        borderWidth: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
```

However, I've noticed that these two buttons share the same styles, and similar styles will be used for others that I'll create. I want to reuse styles because if the default style changes, I only need to modify it in one place.

Here's an example of what I want to do:

```
export const globalStyles = StyleSheet.create({
      buttonDefault: {
        borderRadius: 8,
        padding: 15,
        height: 48,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    buttonContained: {
        **(reuse defaultStyle here)**
        backgroundColor: Colors.primary,
    },
    buttonOutlined: {
        **(reuse defaultStyle here)**
        borderColor: Colors.primary,
        borderWidth: 1,
    },
})
```

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?"

Comment: Why don't you use nativeWind with tailwindCSS? This makes it easy to reuse CSS classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put reusable styles to one style sheet and then use that wherever needed. Something like this:

```js
const defaultStyles = StyleSheet.create({
  buttonDefault: {
    borderRadius: 8,
    padding: 15,
    height: 48,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  }
});

export const globalStyles = StyleSheet.create({
  buttonDefault: {
    ...defaultStyles.buttonDefault
  },
  buttonContained: {
    ...defaultStyles.buttonDefault,
    backgroundColor: Colors.primary,
  },
  buttonOutlined: {
    ...defaultStyles.buttonDefault,
    borderColor: Colors.primary,
    borderWidth: 1,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you want but in a different way, have you tried this?

```
<ButtonOne style={[styles.buttonDefault, styles.buttonContained]} />

<ButtonTwo style={[styles.buttonDefault, styles.buttonOutlined]} />
```

or this:

```
export const globalStyles = StyleSheet.create({
    buttonDefault: {
        borderRadius: 8,
        padding: 15,
        height: 48,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    buttonContained: {
        ...globalStyles.buttonDefault,
        backgroundColor: Colors.primary,
    },
    buttonOutlined: {
        ...globalStyles.buttonDefault,
        borderColor: Colors.primary,
        borderWidth: 1,
    },
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! The first solution works, but as this project is going to be large, I don't think it's very nice to call two styles in the same component. I want to simplify as much as possible, that's why I would like to call 'buttonDefault' within the style itself.

The second solution unfortunately didn't work. I tried following the chatGPT advice and used '...this.buttonDefault', but it didn't work either :(

Comment: Consider making a global stlyes variable in your constants file that can be accessed throughout your app via the first approach I showed.